# how to use sound in Pascal

Tags: pascal

I try to use Sound(x) command with different "x" values, but it only shows a beep, same sound.

```
program Sounds;
uses
   crt;

begin
   Sound(1000);
   Sound(500);
   Delay(1000);
   Sound(300);
   Sound(150);
   Delay(1000);
   NoSound;
end.
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Which compiler, which platform?

Comment: They are Free Pascal IDE and Window 7 64bit.

Comment: Excuse me, it may not be implemented on them? This code worked fine on Turbo Pascal, Window XP. :D

Comment: Afaik they still work on FreePascal/go32v2 (dos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sound` does not work on Windows anymore.

I made a [patch](http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=12437) that works on some systems, but they did not really care about it.

--

`Sound` makes a sound forever / till `NoSound` is called. If you only want to make a sound 
for a certain duration you can use `Beep(freq, duration)` from the windows unit